# reduced conditional understanding

Tags: java

Please compare two code snippets:

non-working code:

```
(1>2)? System.out.println(1):System.out.println(2);
```

working code:

```
 System.out.println((1>2)?1:2);
```

why first variant is not works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two alternatives of the conditional *must* return a value and it must be of the same type, which becomes the value of the overall expression. `System.out.println()` is `void`.

In the second case the two alternatives are `int`s (valid) and the type of the expression is `int`.

And, thanks to the comment from Marko Topolnik: The conditional is not a shorthand for an `if..then..else`; it is an expression thus it cannot occupy the place of a statement.

Comment: *The two alternatives of the conditional must return a value and it must be of the same type, which becomes the value of the overall expression* - full unclear

Comment: *the value of the overall expression* especially